# Proving two series are the same

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

I'm currently coming up with some difficulties proving that these two series are the same. Given that $n$ is a positive integer, $m$ is an integer larger than 2, and $a$ is a nonnegative real number
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{a^{k+1}}{k!}\bigg(\int_0^me^{-ax}x^kdx\bigg)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\bigg(1-\frac{(n-k)}{k!}e^{-am}(am)^k\bigg)$$
My strategy is to prove by induction on $n$. When $n=1$, the RHS and LHS both give $1-e^{-am}$. When $n=2$, it is $2-2e^{-am}-ame^{-am}$.

However, the main difficulty is that by induction, there is no way to avoid integration by part $n$ (or $n-1$) times, which is unrealistic. Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: You have some reason for believing the two are the same?

Comment: It all breaks down when $m\to\infty$.

Comment: You only need to integrate by parts once, then you can set up and solve a recurrence for the antiderivative of $e^{-ax}x^k$.

Comment: This equality comes up with my current research. I have confidence that they are equal. I do not require $m\to\infty$ since it is a finite positive integer in the setting of my research.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$I_k = \int_0^m e^{-ax} x^k \, dx$$

Integrating by parts (only once!), differentiating $x^k$ and integrating $e^{-ax}$, gives the recurrence

$$I_k = \frac ka I_{k-1} - \frac{e^{-am} m^k}a$$
with the starting value
$$I_0 = \int_0^m e^{-ax}\,dx = \frac{1-e^{-am}}a$$

By substitution, we see that

$$\begin{align*}
I_k &= \frac ka I_{k-1} - \frac{e^{-am} m^k}a \\[1ex]
& = \frac{k(k-1)}{a^2} I_{k-2} - \frac{e^{-am}}a \left(m^k + \frac ka m^{k-1}\right) \\[1ex]
&= \frac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{a^3} I_{k-3} - \frac{e^{-am}}a \left(m^k + \frac ka m^{k-1} + \frac{k(k-1)}{a^2} m^{k-2}\right)
\end{align*}$$

and so on; after $i$ rounds of substituting, we end up with

$$I_k = \frac{k(k-1)(k-2)\cdots(k-(i-1))}{a^i} I_{k-i} - \frac{e^{-am}}a \sum_{j=0}^i \frac{k!}{(k-j)!} \frac{m^{k-j}}{a^j}$$

Now let $i=k$.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful recursion relation!